# R vector numeric expression warning

Tags: r

I created a simple vector in R to store the temperatures of 3 patients.

> temperature <- c(98.1, 98.6, 101.4)

then later I tried to retrieve the temperature of the second and third patient.

> temperature[2:3]
>   [1] 98.6 101.4

While trying to retrieve all three values I succeeded but then got this warning from RStudio

> temperature[1:2:3]
>   [1] 98.1 98.6 101.4

Warning message:
In 1:2:3 : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used

What does this warning mean?

Comment: The expression `[1:2:3]` is simply not valid R. What you want it `[1:3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `temperature[1:2:3]` though is valid (valid in the sense that it will compile without errors) in R, but will give you same result as `temperature[1:3]`.

R only uses the first and the last indices. So, `temperature[1:3:4:5:3]` is same as `temperature[1:3]`.